# formatting message from sns publish to https endpoints

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I am publishing messages to a sns_topic and am suing boto3.
I am using https endpoint as protocol. The output message received to the endpoint are included with "/". I tried a way to escape that by doing this

```
def sns_publish(message, sns_event):
    try:
        topic_arn = get_topic_arn(sns_event)        
        customer_id = str(message['customer_id'])
        message = json.dumps({"default":json.dumps(message)})
        sns_client.publish(TopicArn=topic_arn,
                            Message=message,
                           MessageStructure='json',
                           MessageAttributes={
                            'customer_id': {
                                'DataType': 'String',
                                'StringValue': customer_id
                            }})
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("SNSPublishError: {}".format(e))
```

output received to https endpoint is below:

```
"Message": "{\"id\": \"WT3375104\", \"bill_to_nbr_x\": \"7159\", \"file_nbr_x\": \"3375104\"}"
```

I followed the boto3 documentation and gave Message and MessageStructure attributes as shown above in the code, how can I remove those "/" from JSON output

Answer (score 1):

it's aws feature to present sent data in such format, so to parse it use json module:

```
import json

mess = {"Message": "{\"id\": \"WT3375104\", \"bill_to_nbr_x\": \"7159\", \"file_nbr_x\": \"3375104\"}"}

print(json.loads(mess['Message']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [raw message delivery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html)? This should result in the message not looking like an SNS message, which means the message doesn't need to be escaped because it's not included in another JSON object.